# MinGW make file compiles but codeblocks will not build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mingw, codeblocks

I am trying to convert a C program to VB.NET. (I know, just accept I have my reasons and leave it at that).

Anyway, I wasn't sure if the source code I had was any good so after about a week of pulling my hair out I finally downloaded CodeBlocks, grabbed the MinGW directory and I can make working successful build from a command line using Mingw32-make. Now I want to use codeblocks to build the file because ultimately I want to be able to step through the code however when I try I just get a bunch of errors and no exe. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and just need help. For that matter is there anyway to just have MinGW create some kind of debug info that would be usefull in Visual Studio? I am not a C programmer so sorry if it seems obvious.